# Copy and paste / scrolling freezes browser on a particular question

Tags: support, specific-question, google-chrome, browser-support

I'm using Google Chrome version:

> ```
> Google Chrome is up to date
> Version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)
> ```

OS is:

> ```
> OS Name   Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
> Version   10.0.18362 Build 18362
> ```

I've been on this site for 5.5 years and must admit I've never seen this happen before. For this particular question (and no others):
[what are the approaches to create exception handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59461577/what-are-the-approaches-to-create-exception-handler) . The only thing noteworthy with the question may be the amount of data in the first code block, but beyond that I don't see anything particularly unusual in the question when I view it with the Stackoverflows's `edit` question feature.

I'm experiencing problems:

- The syntax highlighting seems to be slow
- The area around the outside of the question seems to flash orange briefly but noticeable enough to see when the question is loading
- Highlighting (to initiate a copy and paste) some of the information in the first code block seems to freeze parts of the browser. After attempting to highlight it fails to highlight and then using the vertical scroll bar on the entire page seems to freeze.
- CPU usage seems abnormally high for the page.

Highlighting (for copy and paste) only seems to be an issue for the large first code block in the question but seems fine for the 2 smaller code blocks at the bottom of the question.

If I use Chrome's incognito mode (the closest you can get to a safe mode with extensions off) I experience the same issue. I tried rebooting the PC, same problem.

If I go to any other questions I have seen today I don't experience the problem. If I use Microsoft Edge it doesn't seem to get stuck but it seems sluggish (but I don't use Edge enough to make a good comparison so maybe it is okay).

Is this happening for others using Chrome when trying to interact with that question?

Comment: For me, text highlighting is slow when selecting near the bottom of the code block, but it's fine at the top. I have decent hardware, but highlighting never *fails* on me, it just takes a second or two

Comment: Interesting, I just tried that here. For me it seems equally bad no matter where I try highlighting ib the first code block. If I attempt to highlight the 2 smaller code blocks at the end of the question those work fine. I have now added that bit of info to the question. I'm doing this on an older quad core i5 system running at about 2.4ghz.

Comment: Perhaps the problem has to do with the sheer number of pretty-printed elements in the <code>, and the browser chokes when trying to figure out exactly what span of text your highlighting covers. Try https://jsfiddle.net/fzetjLs3/ , this is slow for me in areas too, it contains exactly the same HTML as in the code block there.

Comment: If you open that HTML as a standalone file (not in an iframe), and run a performance test, the vast majority of activity is taken up by the "Rendering" section, which is composed nearly entirely of "Hit Test" actions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hit-testing Sounds about right

Comment: @CertainPerformance : aha, the JSFiddle gives me the same kind of behaviour as Stackoverflow. In the result window I can't properly highlight and the vertical and horizontal scroll bars seem frozen. Web development isn't my area of expertise ;-)

Comment: The only thing I know is that this is the first question I've ever encountered and interacted with on this site that exhibits this kind of behaviour.

Comment: Seems to be a chrome v79 only issue. Could reproduce here (on macOs if it matters), and using latest Canary (81), the issue is gone. Will run a bisect if I got time.

Comment: So bisect pointed to this [CR](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/d91cd688b1ddaf62f5ac60296e677a4c0ece84e9) being the defect culprit and [this one](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/22157a47a4fc1574fb5bcba0490673ba60bd5bba) being the fix. Already reported in  [this crbug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1008523). Seems to be caused by the high number of <span> elements in the page, not sure SO should/can do anything here though.

Comment: @Kaiido : Yep that seems to be the culprit.

Comment: Same problem can be observed with a similarly huge code block [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59551295) on Chrome 79